# show modal and wait till user click on a button in the modal angularjs

Tags: angularjs

please I need help.

I'm using Dan Wahlin's service http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/09/18/building-an-angularjs-modal-service.aspx and I am calling it from my controller.

After modal is shown I want the code won't execute the next code lines untill user clicks on the OK button in the modal.

Is it possible?

My code:

```
var modalInfo = new ModalInfo();
modalInfo.ModalOptions.CloseText = "close";
modalInfo.ModalOptions.OKText = "OK";
modalInfo.ModalOptions.BodyMessage = "Hello";
modalInfo.ModalOptions.Template = "popup.html";


modalService.showModal({}, modalInfo.ModalOptions).then(function () {
    //Some code
});

var a = 1;
 alert(a);
```

Meaning alert with a value will appear after user clicks OK in the modal

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. JavaScript is based on asynchronous events. The code to execute once the user has clicked the OK button should go in the callback function passed to `then()`